hpack other-extensioin OverloadedStrings has no effect
I use in every module the extension {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} and thought I can include it in hpack as
other-extensions:  
- OverloadedStrings  

hpack parses ok, but the Haskell code is not compiled with the extension.
What is my error?
